# Effect of sched_setaffinity() on new threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, affinity

Does `sched_setaffinity()`, when called from a "main" process, affect the running core on which new threads are created from this running process?

From what I see, all the threads that are created after calling `sched_setaffinity()` are always created on the same core that the "main" process was set to run on. Is this something I can rely on to happen every time the program is executed?

In the following pseudo-code, is it guaranteed that threadA, threadB and threadC will always be running on the same core?

```
int main()
{
   sched_setaffinity(...);
   threadA = std::thread();
   threadB = std::thread();
   threadC = std::thread();
}
```

Comment: What is `sched_setaffinnnity`?

Comment: @eerorika : https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity

Comment: Short answer: yes. Threads respect the affinity of the parent process.